# Error in copying files to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I tried installing hadoop in two nodes. Both the nodes are up and running. The namenode runs on Ubuntu 10.10 and Datanode on Fedora 13. While copying the file from local file system to hdfs I encountered the following errors.

The terminal showed:

```
    12/04/12 02:19:15 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream java.io.OException: Bad connect ack with firstBadLink as 10.211.87.162:9200
    12/04/12 02:19:15 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning block blk_-1069539184735421145_1014
```

The log file in namenode showed:

```
   2012-10-16 16:17:56,723 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(10.6.2.26:50010, storageID=DS-880164535-10.18.13.10-50010-1349721715148, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver
   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
         at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
         at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
         at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:404)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.writeBlock(DataXceiver.java:282)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataXceiver.run(DataXceiver.java:103)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Datanodes available are indicated as 2. I've disabled the firewall and selinux.
The following changes have also been made in the hdfs-site.xml

dfs.socket.timeout -> 360000

dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout  -> 3600000

dfs.datanode.max.xcievers    ->  1048576

Both the nodes run sun-java6-jdk, The datanode contains Openjdk but the path settings have been made for sun java.

Yet the same error persists.

What might be the solution.

Comment: Check the network connectivity by doing a ping between the different machines.

Comment: @PraveenSripati Yes, the machines are connected. Checked with ping. Yet problem persists.

Comment: did you find the solution ? I'm currently facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 3):

That's because your firewall is on.

try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

If you are on Ubuntu, do

```
sudo ufw disable
```

this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The exception log mentioned tha the failure reason is `No route to host`.

Try `ping 10.6.2.26` to test your network connection.